# Dealing with both categorical and numerical variables in a Multiple Linear Regression Python

Tags: pandas, python-2.7, scikit-learn, linear-regression

So I have already performed a multiple linear regression in Python using LinearRegression from sklearn.

My independant variables were all numerical (and so was my dependant one)

But now I'd like to perform a multiple linear regression combining numerical and non numerical independant variables.

Therefore I have several questions:

- If I use dummy variables or One-Hot for the non-numerical ones, will I then be able to perform the LinearRegression from sklearn?
- If yes, do I have to change some parameters?
- If not, how should I perform the Linear Regression?
- One thing that bother me is that dummy/one-hot methods don't deal with ordinal variables, right? (Because it shouldn't be encoded the same way in my opinion)
- Problem is: Even if I want to encode diffently nominal and ordinal variables,
  it seems impossible for Python to tell the difference between both of them?

This stuff might be easy for you but right now as you could tell I'm a little confused so I could really use your help !

Thanks in advance,

Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If I use dummy variables or One-Hot for the non-numerical ones, will I then be able to perform the LinearRegression from sklearn?

In fact the model has to be fed exclusively with numerical data, thus you must use OneHot vectors for the categorical data in your input features. For that you can take a look at Scikit-Learn's [LabelEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) and [OneHotEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html).

- One thing that bother me is that dummy/one-hot methods don't deal with ordinal variables, right? (Because it shouldn't be encoded the same way in my opinion)

Yes. As you mention one-hot methods don't deal with ordinal variables. One way to work with ordinal features is to create a scale map, and map those features to that scale. [Ordinal](http://contrib.scikit-learn.org/categorical-encoding/ordinal.html) is a very useful tool for these cases. You can feed it a mapping dictionary according to a predifined scale mapping as mentioned. Otherwise, obviously it randomly assigns integers to the different categories as it has no knowledge to infer any order. From the documentation:

> Ordinal encoding uses a single column of integers to represent the classes. An optional mapping dict can be passed in, in this case we use the knowledge that there is some true order to the classes themselves. Otherwise, the classes are assumed to have no true order and integers are selected at random.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Alexandre, it definitely helps ! I'm going to look at Ordinal right now. But as for my last bullet point, it seems impossible for Python to distinguish nominal variables from ordinal ones, right? So I'm kind of stuck there I guess?

Comment: No. @Alex. Only tou have the knowledge of whether or not your features are ordinal or nominal, and you will thus have to do some preprocessing steps in order to feed meaningful features to your model. Glad it helped

Comment: Thus it makes it impossible for me to perform this linear regression. Is there a way around it?

Comment: You have these two options, as I mentioned. Or you OneHot encode your features, but lose the order information that they provide and see if your model gains something; or create a mapping of your ordinal features to say integers that respect the ordinality of your categorical feature.